# ClientDC and WindowDC do not draw under Fedora 16 Gnome 3, only PaintDC

Tags: linux, wxpython, fedora, gnome-3, gdi

I am writing an app which draws text and shapes in a ClientDC of a Frame. When I run the app under my Fedora 16(Gnome 3) nothing is drawn in the Frame, but if I run it under Windows all drawings display normally.

I've tried using WindowDC to do the drawing on, but it is not different to ClientDC under Fedora. I can only get a successful drawing when using PaintDC.

Am I doing something wrong(or missing something), or is it just Linux/Fedora/Gnome 3?

Answer (score 1):

I think the recommended way to paint is with the newer wx.GCDC with a fallback to the wx.PaintDC. If you need advanced drawing, see FloatCanvas, cairo or the glcanvas.